# brick-breaker game:paddle does not show up-undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build brick-breaker game, however, the paddle does not show up. Seems like `this.position.x, this.position.y, this.width, this.height` is undefined..does anyone know why?? please help

```
let canvas=document.querySelector('.canvas')
let ctx=canvas.getContext('2d')

const gameWidth=800;
const gameHeight=500;

// ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 800, 500)


/////////////paddle class//////////
class Paddle{
    constructor(gameWidth, gameHeight){
        this.width=150;
        this.height=30;
        this.position={
            x:gameWidth/2-this.width/2,
            y:gameHeight-this.height-10
        };
    }

    draw(ctx){
        ctx.fillStyle='#32a852'
        ctx.fillRect(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.width, this.height)
    }
}
//////////controller///////
let paddle=new Paddle(gameWidth,gameHeight);
paddle.draw(ctx);///not working
ctx.fillRect(10,10,10,10)//this working
```

Comment: How are you including these in your HTML?
Does app.js know what ctx is? In other words, is the code above paddle.js somewhere else than in app.js? If so then ctx will be undefined

Comment: HTML simply just <canvas class="canvas"></canvas> and link to app.js which is the one you see above. I put paddle.js and app.js together. ctx is define since ctx.fillReact works

Comment: Did you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're paddle position is not within the canvas size. Try adding this below the canvas variable definition `canvas.width = window.innerWidth; canvas.height = window.innerHeight;`

I tested it on my machine and it worked, so I hope this helps and if you need any clarification let me know!

Comment: problem solved!!! but I totally don't understand why..
this is my css for canvas
.canvas{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 800px;
    height: 500px; 
    border: 2px solid black;
}

I also tried to add width and height directly to canvas HTML, it works without canvas.width = window.innerWidth; canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

Comment: That only styles the style width, if you want a specific width and height use the DOM width and height ie `canvas.width` and `canvas.height` :) also it solves the problem because the x position and y position of your paddle is not within the canvas's size so it wouldn't be rendered within the canvas screen